# Automatically Call onBindViewHolder on rotate

Tags: java, android

I am working on my app and it requires the movie posters to be 1:2 ratio. I have found a way to do this is to run

```
        movieAdapterViewHolder.posterview.requestLayout();
    ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = movieAdapterViewHolder.cardview.getViewTreeObserver();
    if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                movieAdapterViewHolder.cardview.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                movieAdapterViewHolder.posterview.getLayoutParams().height = Double.valueOf(movieAdapterViewHolder.posterview.getWidth() * 1.5).intValue();
            }
        });
    }
```

However, this doesn't get called immediately on rotate. It only gets called from `onBindViewHolder`. Is there any other way to set the height of a CardView in a RecyclerView to 2x it's width or how can I somehow call onBindViewHolder?

Comment: Where is this code segment located? Inside `onCreate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can notify your adapter about changes that you have made by calling `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` . it calls onBindViewHolder and changes your items view with latest changes.

Comment: Didn't work but thanks for the help. Just gonna check your answer because I ended up fixing it differently.